# Turn similar rows into columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'doc':['john','john','john', 'mary', 'mary', 'mary'], 'token':[1,2,3,4,5,6,]})
```

How do I turn it into:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'john':[1,2,3],'mary':[4,5,6]})
```

I've tried pivot, pivot_table, stack, and unstack but had no success.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` to create a dummy index then use `pivot` to get the expected dataframe:

```
>>> (df.assign(index=df.groupby('doc').cumcount())
       .pivot(index='index', columns='doc', values='token')
       .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

   john  mary
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

**Update**: Suggested by @Chrysophylaxs using `pivot_table`:

```
>>> (df.pivot_table(columns="doc", index=df.groupby("doc").cumcount(), values="token")
       .rename_axis(columns=None))

   john  mary
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

Comment: thanks. still had to do some more things: pd.DataFrame(list(df.groupby('doc').agg(list).to_dict().values())[0])

Comment: What about `df.pivot_table(columns="doc", index=df.groupby("doc").cumcount(), values="token")`?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs. You are right. I always forget it's possible to add a dynamic index/column to `pivot_table`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs. I updated my answer according your comment and gave you the credit

Comment: Appreciate it @Corralien, was playing around with stack and unstack but could not get it to work until I saw your initial suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
df_cols = pd.DataFrame({k: v.reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby('doc')['token']})
```

Output:

```
   john  mary
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```